# How can i make a program to read packets sent from a site?

Tags: http, sockets, web-scraping

I want to create a program to interface with a site.

I want the program to collect all the data that the site would be transmitting to me if i had the site window open, and then i want my program to perform data analysis.

I'm obviously not looking for a complete explanation, but am wondering where to start.

Ultimately, my question is:

Do i use socket programming? Is there a way to route all packets from that site into my program and convert the packet data to manipulatable info?

Or do i have to do it another way?

Edit: Also i have some familiarity with Java

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about a web proxy?

Here is the developer info to write your own scripts for Fiddler:
http://fiddler2.com/Fiddler/dev/ScriptSamples.asp

or

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

or if you need detailed packet info

http://www.wireshark.org/

If you just know a little java, you're not going to accomplish this on your own right away IMHO.

Comment: Dude, use the fiddler scripts feature to write custom implementations.